# NEST 2.0 and ElasticSearch 2.0 unable to mock a "return all" query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, mocking, moq, nest

This is the query I want to mock:

```
  var readRecords = elastic.Search<GroupRecord>(s => s
        .Index(indexName)
        .Query(q => q.
            QueryString(qs => qs.Query("*"))));
```

and this is the actual Moq

```
var groupResp = new Mock<ISearchResponse<GroupRecord>>();
var groupRecords = new[]
{
     new GroupRecord
     {
          GroupName = "blablabla"
     }
};

groupResp.SetupGet(x => x.Documents).Returns(groupRecords);
ElasticClientMock.Setup(ec => ec.Search(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<GroupRecord>, SearchDescriptor<GroupRecord>>>())).Returns(groupResp.Object);
```

On NEST1.0 and ElasticSearch1.0 the query was returning all (1) documents. On the new NEST2.0 and ElasticSearch2.0 my `readRecords` is `null`.

Do you know why?

**EDIT**

On a real environment (no mocking) the query returns all the documents as expected

Comment: Can you include the signature of the `Search` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the Setup.  The following line:

```
ElasticClientMock.Setup(ec => ec.Search(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<GroupRecord>, SearchDescriptor<GroupRecord>>>())).Returns(groupResp.Object);
```

Mock is looking for a Func<> with two `SearchDescriptor` objects, which it was in NEST1.  Now, I think the signature for Search is a Func<> with one `SearchDescriptor` and one `ISearchRequest`.